# Why ActiveMQ 5.14.x can't start embedded with camel-jms component 2.18.3

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

Here is the simple spring boot project (version `1.5.2`) to demonstrate the problem:

https://github.com/lanwen/camel-jms-activemq-test

It has **Apache Camel** version **2.18.3**

On branch `master` all works fine because of `activemq-camel=5.14.4` and `camel-jms=2.16.3` (gets transitively from it)

Spring boot application starts normally with log:

```
2017-04-22 00:53:19.647  INFO 97217 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2017-04-22 00:53:19.662  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.4 (localhost, ID:lanwen-osx3.local-62145-1492811599544-0:1) is starting
2017-04-22 00:53:19.665  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.4 (localhost, ID:lanwen-osx3.local-62145-1492811599544-0:1) started
2017-04-22 00:53:19.665  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
2017-04-22 00:53:19.682  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://localhost started
2017-04-22 00:53:19.702  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: route1 started and consuming from: activemq://queue:to-write?asyncConsumer=true
2017-04-22 00:53:19.703  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
2017-04-22 00:53:19.704  INFO 97173 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.466 seconds
2017-04-22 00:53:19.709  INFO 97173 --- [           main] ru.yandex.test.writer.MyTestApplication  : Started MyTestApplication in 2.437 seconds (JVM running for 2.911)
```

But when you start with `camel-jms=2.18.3` (as the main version of camel, on branch [not_working](https://github.com/lanwen/camel-jms-activemq-test/tree/not_working))

Things go wrong with this log:

```
2017-04-22 00:56:38.070  INFO 97195 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
...
2017-04-22 00:56:43.590  WARN 97195 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
```

But if we change `activemq-camel` to `5.13.4` with `camel-jms=2.18.3` it works fine again...

Why ActiveMQ **5.14.x** doesn't work with camel-jms **2.18.x**?

Comment: I have a project with camel-version=2.18.0 and activeMQ-version=5.14.1 and it working fine. Can add some more traces?

Comment: Did you try example project? https://github.com/lanwen/camel-jms-activemq-test. Also please check that your camel-jms version is not 2.16.x

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the dependency list for the latest Camel ActiveMQ `1.15.5` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-camel/5.14.5), you'll see that it already has `camel-jms` as a dependency, but the version is `1.16.3`. So there's no need for you to separately add a `camel-jms` `1.18.x` dependency in your POM, because it will overwrite the `1.16.x` version that ActiveMQ already uses, which is the compatible one.

So essentially, the issue is that you're trying to use a newer, incompatible version of `camel-jms`. When you separately add the `1.18.x` `camel-jms` dependency, the ActiveMQ componenet will use this version, which is not compatible with its `1.16.x` version, and hence, the error.

If you need to use ActiveMQ, then you'll probably have to see if `camel-jms` `1.16.x` will work for you.

Comment: Sure, I know it has this version of the dependency. But the problem is that it don't work by default of you simply uses camel bom, or/and spring-boot bom. And the question is why it don't work exactly in this combination of versions and still works with another